# Markowitz portfolio mean variance optimization in R

Tags: r

I have 5 emerging market foreign exchange total return series, for which I am forecasting single period future returns (1 year). I would like to construct a Markowitz mean variance optimized portfolio of the 5 series, using historical variances and covariances (1) and my own forecast expected returns. Does R have an (easy) way/library to do this? In addition how would I go about calculating (1) is there a built in function?

For interest sake my currencies are USDTRY, USDZAR, USDRUB, USDHUF and USDPLN.

Comment: This belongs on quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: True in theory, but in practise quant.stackexchange.com is targeted at "professionals" and doesn't want to cater for learners, as I have discovered (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/250?m=1097065#1097065).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might look at the following:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tawny/index.html

http://www.rinfinance.com/RinFinance2009/presentations/yollin_slides.pdf

http://nurometic.com/quantitative-finance/tawny/portfolio-optimization-with-tawny

http://quantivity.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/minimum-variance-portfolios/

Comment: and why didn't I find all this stuff! Awesome thanks Bill.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning this topic there was quite recently a fantastic Coursera MOOC from Professor Eric Zivot from the University of Washington:
[Introduction to computational finance and Financial Econometrics](https://class.coursera.org/compfinance-2012-001/wiki/view?page=Resources)

In case you don't have access there they will offer this course again starting Dec 17th 2012: 
https://www.coursera.org/course/compfinance

Meanwhile most of the material can be found here too:
http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/econ424.htm